# How do I ask for a leave with my manager?

Tags: india, leave

Scenario:

- I have a FE exam coming soon to get licensed as an engineer.
- The work I do doesn't require me to get licensed as an engineer.
- But I want to further my career and I want to give that exam, get my license and become a valid Engineer.
- Similarly, I am not very satisfied with my job prospects (salary, type of work etc), so I need to seek for alternatives as well, so I need to study for that.

I asked for leave with my manager that I want to "study for FE exam" and he was very reluctant to give it, although finally he gave it after doing some bothering and warning me he won't give me a leave afterwards.

What I don't understand is I've tons of leave pending. Like 2 weeks of leaves remaining when I include sick leaves and annual leaves. And my year is about to end(i.e I've already worked for 9 months or so and haven't took much leaves).

In this scenario, how do I ask for a leave? The thing is I am getting conscious about my career, future so I am going to take the leave regardless of it gets approved or not(i.e even unpaid leave), but I'm wondering if I can still convince the manager to give me leave 1 day every 14 days to study. As I said, if I owe to take leaves and I don't get anything in return for not taking those leaves, why should not I be able to take those leaves?

Comment: "I am going to take the leave regardless of it gets approved or not(i.e even unpaid leave)" Errr... taking leave without permission generally gets you fired, not just not paid for those days. Make sure this is really what you want.

Comment: But stepping back here "As I said, if I owe to take leaves and I don't get anything in return for not taking those leaves, why should not I be able to take those leaves?" isn't a question we can answer.

Comment: Is this the norm everywhere? That you don't get your allocated leaves?

Comment: This is why you never explain why you're taking leave. Just say "personal time" if anyone asks.

Comment: @PhilipKendall he keeps asking "why, why, why" though. I will apply this idea from now on. I've not took much leaves so far. So much so that I still have 14 days of leaves remaining along with extra 9 days leaves and I've only 2 months remaining to complete 1 year.

Comment: You're living in fairy world, if you think any manager gives you leave without telling any valid reason lol.

Comment: By "leave", do you mean PTO?  If you want to use your PTO, no justification should be needed, it's your time to use.  If it is some other type of paid leave, then absolutely you need to explain and get permission.  In many locales "leave" is used to refer to medical or other paid time that is not PTO

Comment: It's called annual leave here, I am not aware of any PTOs. I think that's what is called forced leave here which is of 9 days. He didn't let another new guy take it lol.

Comment: PTO stands for paid time off also called vacation  or holiday in some areas.  Sounds the same as your annual leave, when he asks why tell him it's personal and leavbe it at that

Comment: I request my leave with reasons such as "Vacation" or "Out of Town" and that's it. I'm sorry you don't get such freedoms at your workplace. Also 9  months is not that long to have been working without vacations, and it sounds like you want to take everything you've accrued all at once, on short notice, to take a test so you can move on from your job. Why would your manager approve that?

Comment: @barnyard9 1) not giving a reason for leave has worked pretty well for me in my 20 year career 2) "personal time" is a perfectly valid reason for time off, if you really get pushed just say "spending some time with my family"

Comment: "I am going to take the leave regardless of it gets approved or not" - This is a great way to be fired for cause, not having your reasonable request, to use your annual leave is a seperate problem than not actually showing up to work when you are expected to be there.

Comment: why do you feel the need to explain what the leave is for? it's your holiday pool, you can use it up to lie on the floor of your room and stare at the ceiling if that's what you want, it's nothing to do with your manager

Comment: @InBedded16 I'm getting the idea he wants to use what he is entitled to because the leave is generally lost if you don't use it up until the end of business year, which is generally the smart thing to do

Answer (score 5):

No sane business will give you additional leave to build your skills so you can quit.

So take your personal time off in whatever fashion it exists to study.  You don't say anything about why you are going to be off, you're taking personal time.  Taking time off that is not approved means you're quitting and you will likely be fired.

Comment: You're living in fairy world, if you think any manager gives you leave without telling any valid reason lol. I wonder what culture you're from?

Comment: @barnyard9, the attitude you're bringing here isn't terribly productive. You've asked in other comments whether it's the norm everywhere that you don't get your allocated leave, and Tiger Guy is giving you an answer that's correctly based on the fact that no, that's not the norm. In many work cultures, employees do not need to provide any explanation or justification when requesting to use the paid leave to which they're contractually entitled.

Comment: @barnyard9 Merica..

Comment: @barnyard9 - I actually do it all the time.  I request leave, in order to use the leave that was granted, as part of my compensation.  I am granted 14 days a year, I can use that time, for any reason I want. I also have a separate pool of leave that is exclusively for being sick or for doctor's appointment. My manager would have to have a very good reason deny my leave request.

Comment: @barnyard9, USA.  If a manager asked me what I was doing during my vacation I would tell them "enjoying my time off."

Comment: @barnyard9 Even granting that you're from a culture where you need to give a valid reason to take the leave, why not just lie about it? You're planning to quit anyway.

Comment: I am planning to quit but on good terms though. My family recommended me to provide this reason.